# Code Signed Application Generates Warning Message

Tags: windows, sha1, sha256, codesign

Being fully aware of the depreciation of SHA1 and having access to an SHA256 certificate (issued by Comodo) which I have installed to my system and am using to code-sign project executables (in this case, the project executable is an INNO compiled setup file), I am continuing to receive complaints from users about seeing this warning message :

[image]

This is the command that I am using to code sign with (I have added the path to SignTool.exe to the system Path variable so I do not qualify it completely when I call it; Also, the command is in a .bat file):

```
SignTool.exe sign /v /a /fd sha256 /du "http://www.foo.bar" %1
```

My first guess is that I am not using the SignTool sign command correctly. I know that the certificate is installed because I have seen it when I looked with the `Certmgr.msc`. More evidence that the code sign is successful :

[image]

Why is this still happening?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the problem is specifically, but you can verify the signature after signing using [`SignTool.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx#Verify)

I use it with the following arguments:
`signtool.exe verify /pa /v [pathToSignedFile]`

Comment: This cannot be an answer.

Comment: I would have left a comment instead but I don't have 50 rep, just trying to be helpful :)